# How to add UIImageView adding to mail?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

How to add a  image to mail which is dinamically add to uiimageview.

Comment: Well that is a short question, could you at least tell us what you tried, show us some code or errors...

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)sendMailWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
if(mailController!=nil) {
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[mailController addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"MyImageName"];
[mailController setSubject:yourSubject];
[mailController setMessageBody:yourBody isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
[mailController release];
}
else
{
//Do something like show an alert
}
}
```

also read this for more help

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/email/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-example-using-iphone-camera-to-email-a-photo.html

Comment: +1, it uses the same method I have suggested on my answer

Comment: in the above code the image will be add statistically, in my project which will have to dynamically,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MFMailComposeViewController, you can use this method of that view controller:

> addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName: Adds the specified data as an
> attachment to the message.
>
> -(void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename
>
> Parameters
>
> - attachment
>
> The data to attach. Typically, this is the contents of a
> file that you want to include. This parameter must not be nil.
>
> - mimeType
>
> The MIME type of the specified data. (For example, the MIME
> type for a JPEG image is image/jpeg.) For a list of valid MIME types,
> see http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/. This parameter must
> not be nil.
>
> - filename
>
> The preferred filename to associate with the
> data. This is the default name applied to the file when it is
> transferred to its destination. Any path separator (/) characters in
> the filename are converted to underscore (_) characters prior to
> transmission. This parameter must not be nil.
>
> Discussion
>
> This method
> attaches the specified data after the message body but before the
> user’s signature. You may attach multiple files (using different file
> names) but must do so prior to displaying the mail composition
> interface. Do not call this method after presenting the interface to
> the user.